# Understanding of the parameter model.infer_vector for doc2vec gensim

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

[image]

Does it mean that I must provide tokenized words of a document as list of strings or simply a document as a list of string for the input doc_words. Please clarify

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the infer\_vector in gensim.doc2vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993240/how-to-use-the-infer-vector-in-gensim-doc2vec)

Comment: @WiLL_K Yes the question quoted by you answers my doubt. Thank you so much your clarification rectified my model performance from 36% to 79%. I was feeding the input as whole document but I understood that we must feed the tokens of a document. Keep up your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `doc_words` should be a list of individual word-tokens as strings, equivalent to the `words` of each training document during training. That is: it should have been preprocessed and tokenized the same as your training data was.

(When you ask in your question, "tokenized words of a document as list of strings or simply a document as a list of string", as far as I understand those words, those two alternatives are the same thing: a Python `list`, where each item is a string word.)

Other important things to note about `infer_vector()`:

- inference always starts with a low-magnitude random vector, then iteratively improves that vector
- words not known to the model will be silently ignored; at the extreme, if you supply a text with all unknown words, no inference will happen – but because of the random initialization above, you'll still get a vector back
- if you don't specify an `epochs` value, it will reuse the value cached in the model (left over from model initialization or your last `train()` call). You will generally want it to use a number of epochs at least as large as was used in training – which is most commonly 10-20, but sometimes larger. (And, larger values may be especially helpful with shorter texts.)